# Представления Views проекта C# asp net core сверстанные с помощью bootstrap 4 некорректно отображаются в мобильных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap4, asp.net-core-mvc, mobile-web

Есть проект  C# asp net core mvc, представления в нем .cshtml стандартно сверстаны с помощью  bootstrap 4.
В браузере в режиме разработчика мобильной версии меню сайта работает открывается:
[image: Открытие мобильной версии в браузере]

Но когда открывается на реальном мобильном телефоне (с предпоследней версией Android), то это меню не раскрывается, по нему щелкаешь оно активируется, но список с ссылками не выпадает.

Проверил на ресурсе google оптимизацию под мобайл, он выдал, что сервис оптимизирован под мобайл, но некоторые ресурсы не удалось загрузить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина?
Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Код главной страницы _Layout.cshtml:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - CollectVoters</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/font-glyphicons.css">
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"> 2021</a></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Администратор</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Friends" asp-action="Index">Личный кабинет</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Регистрация</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Причина в коде. Исправить можно. Код вы не привели - поэтому вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AK, код чего нужно привести, представления?

Comment: @AK, привел код

Comment: Что-то я не помню в типовых примерах на navbar в четвёртом бутстрапе смеси с флексами. Зачем вы добавили эти флексы, они точно там нужны? Я бы предложил попробовать убрать их и если результат устроит -- то вернуться к вопросу "какую проблему вы решали флексами?" и попробовать решить иначе, чтобы не поехала вёрстка на мобильных.

Comment: @AK, что за флексы? Страницу брал по дефолту, ничего не добавлял. Что нужно попробовать удалить?

Comment: d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse и  flex-grow-1, также полезно поставить в браузер расширение которое показывает текущий режим сайта (sm, xl, md) чтобы понять на каком конкретно layout'е происходит неправильный показ.

Comment: @AK, вы были правы, после того как я отключил эти элементы мобильная версия начала нормально, ну или почти нормально работать (масштабирование конечно хромает, но это уже др. вопрос). Напишите свой ответ я отмечу.